# How to use custom Js template file on react/Gatsby?

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

This is my first time here. I've already spent two days trying to resolve the problem.

I'm new at react/gatsby development, I purchased a html template with CSS/js files, I found the way to import the CSS files and actually the js files on the gatsby-ssr.js, when I run gatsby develop command the site gives me the next error on console, stopping the template js files to working:

> react-dom.development.js:67 Warning: Expected server HTML to contain a matching `<p>` in `<div>`.
> at p
> at div
> at div
> at div
> at div
> at div
> at div
> at section
> at div
> at StaticQueryDataRenderer

but when I run gatsby serve, like in production, the error is gone and the js files works flawlessly.
Already tried to use "useEffect" to control DOM objects, but the custom js files from the template use jQuery to use another libraries loaded by a js file on the gatsby-ssr.js file. Also tried to modify the default html.js with no solution.

I think it's the execution time, these js template files need to load at the end of the html page rendering, that's because in html template works fine, but no in react components importing the custom js template files.

All I want is rid off the red warning console sign and let the custom js template file to work fine, while I'm on develop mode of gatsby. I'm going crazy haha.

> Edit

I will try to explain what I'm doing and what how it supposed to work.

1: The template has a file called main.js which includes this code.

```js
    if ($('#breaking_slider').length > 0) {
        $('#breaking_slider').owlCarousel({
            items: 1,
            loop: true,
            dots: false,
            nav: true,
            animateOut: 'slideOutDown',
            animateIn: 'flipInX',
            autoplayTimeout: 5000,
            autoplay: true,
        })
    }
```

2: I use gatsby-ssr.js to import the main.js file like this.

```js
    import React from 'react'
    import { withPrefix, Link } from "gatsby"

    export const replaceRenderer = ({ setPostBodyComponents }) => {
       setPostBodyComponents([
            // .... more template scripts
            <script
                key={withPrefix('main.js')}
                src={withPrefix('main.js')}
                crossOrigin="anonymous"
                defer
            />,
      ])
    }
```

3: created a component called nav with the next code, which I use on a layout.js and a index.js page

```js
    <section className="top-bar transparent">
        <div className="container">
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col-md-12 align-self-center">
                    <div className="ts-breaking-news clearfix">
                        <h2 className="breaking-title float-left">
                            <i className="fa fa-bolt"></i> Breaking News :</h2>
                        <div className="breaking-news-content owl-carousel float-left" id="breaking_slider">
                            <div className="breaking-post-content">
                                <p>
                                    <a href="./">Netcix cuts out the chill with an integrated personal trainer on running.</a>
                                </p>
                            </div>
                            <div className="breaking-post-content">
                                <p>
                                    <a href="./">Parquet Courts on Resisting Nihilism & Why Tourism in Dubai is booming the world.</a>
                                </p>
                            </div>
                            <div className="breaking-post-content">
                                <p>
                                    <a href="/">Parquet Courts on Resisting Nihilism & Why Tourism in Dubai is booming the world.</a>
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

4: When I use the command gatsby develop for a second the index.js works well, using the main.js and modifying the DOM object, but after that throws the next error on console and stop the execution of the main.js an the modified visuals in the first second.

```sh
    react-dom.development.js:67 Warning: Expected server HTML to contain a matching <p> in <div>.
    at p
    at div
    at div
    at div
    at div
    at div
    at div
    at section
    at div
    at StaticQueryDataRenderer
```

5: If I actually use gatsby serve command instead gatsby develop like in production, the error gone, but the most curious is the main.js execution never stops, so the component works well, and actually the template js files used in the gatsby-ssr.js works like suppose to be.

Conclusion: My thought is the execution flow, I have experience on languages like PHP which the order of the template can do problems like this, but never use at depth a language like js on react, I know this works different as compiling the js files, but I tried to move where is loaded this js template files, I tried to replace the main.js with actual useEffect inside the components, but main.js is on jQuery and use other libraries loaded in the same way, so that doesn't solve the problem.

Ty everyone for reading this it is long, but had to describe what happens to express my problem in a better way.

Comment: jQuery doesn't work well in a React environment (DOM vs vDOM), it can lead you to hydration issues. In addition, only sawing an error prompted but not the code that generates it's impossible to fix. Share more details of some implementations, please... You showed warnings, warnings are hidden in build mode unless they become errors. That's why you don't see it in build mode

Comment: I modified the original post with most information, i appreciate you're time and responses!

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. please take a moment and read this article https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask about how to asking questions also read this article https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example about how to ask a good question with minimum requirement.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a lot to comment but I would recommend you to get rid of jQuery and imports like this in your templates:

```
if ($('#breaking_slider').length > 0) {
    $('#breaking_slider').owlCarousel({
        items: 1,
        loop: true,
        dots: false,
        nav: true,
        animateOut: 'slideOutDown',
        animateIn: 'flipInX',
        autoplayTimeout: 5000,
        autoplay: true,
    })
}
```

This file, among pointing directly to the DOM instead of to the virtual DOM (vDOM) that React generates is never being unmounted. This means, that because it's outside the scope of React (React is not aware of the changes in the real DOM), navigation through pages will never stop the execution of that files, implying a huge decrease in performance (this function could seem meaningless but resources are getting accumulated).

You can easily refactor a function like this in a React-based environment using the [`owl-carousel`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-owl-carousel) React-based library:

```
<OwlCarousel className='owl-theme' loop margin={10} nav>
    <div class='item'>
        <h4>1</h4>
    </div>
    <div class='item'>
        <h4>2</h4>
    </div>
    <div class='item'>
        <h4>3</h4>
    </div>
</OwlCarousel>
```

That's why there are specific React-based dependencies indeed.

The snippet above can be an isolated component.

If you still want to integrate jQuery with React, I will add an integration example from React's documentation at the end of the answer but keep in mind you need to handle this kind of mounting/unmounting side-effects.

Regarding your warnings: check the structure of the component. It should be something like:

```
export default function NavBar(props){

return    <section className="top-bar transparent">
        <div className="container">
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col-md-12 align-self-center">
                    <div className="ts-breaking-news clearfix">
                        <h2 className="breaking-title float-left">
                            <i className="fa fa-bolt"></i> Breaking News :</h2>
                        <div className="breaking-news-content owl-carousel float-left" id="breaking_slider">
                            <div className="breaking-post-content">
                                <p>
                                    <a href="./">Netcix cuts out the chill with an integrated personal trainer on running.</a>
                                </p>
                            </div>
                            <div className="breaking-post-content">
                                <p>
                                    <a href="./">Parquet Courts on Resisting Nihilism & Why Tourism in Dubai is booming the world.</a>
                                </p>
                            </div>
                            <div className="breaking-post-content">
                                <p>
                                    <a href="/">Parquet Courts on Resisting Nihilism & Why Tourism in Dubai is booming the world.</a>
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

}
```

> created a component called nav with the next code, which I use on a
> `layout.js` and a `index.js` page

Ideally, your `index.js` should extend from your `Layout`, so you won't need to import the navbar twice, since as soon as you import it in the Layout, it will be available in the `index.js`.

```
const Layout = ({children})=>{
return <main>
   <NavBar />
   {children}
   </main>
}
```

Resources:

- https://reactjs.org/docs/integrating-with-other-libraries.html